# Statement of a general form of Hensel's lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra, hensels-lemma

Let $R$ be a complete ring with respect to ideal $I$ and $p \in R[x]$ polynomial. Element $a \in R$ is an approximate root of $p$ if 
$$
p(a) \in p'(a)^2 I.
$$
One of the general forms of Hensel's lemma states that if there is an approximate root then there is a root $b$ of $p$ such that $a-b \in p'(a)I$. I understand the proof of this fact (see Eisenbud's textbook on commutative algebra), but I'm confused by the condition $p(a) \in p'(a)^2 I$. Why this is a natural condition to put in this statement?

Comment: It's natural, since it's used in the proof.

Comment: I don't find it to be a convincing argument.

Comment: If $p'(a_n)$ is not small enough compared to $p(a_n)$ then you can't construct a root $a_{n+1}\bmod I^{n+1}$ from a root $a_n\bmod I^n$, but you also need that the condition $p'(a_{n+1})$ is small enough compared to $p(a_{n+1})$ stays true,  altogether you get a condition for that the gradient descent with a given initial point $a_1$ converges to a root (in $\varprojlim R/I^n$). Nobody said this condition is necessary, it is sufficient.